# Transformation of Random Variables Involving Division

Tags: probability

I have been working on this problem from a previous exam in Probability theory but I can't understand the next step I am supposed to take. Here is the problem:

Suppose that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent exponential random variables with
parameter 1 and let $X=\frac{Z_1}{Z_1 + Z_2}$.
Find the cumulative distribution function of X and identify the corresponding distribution.

I tried this:
$$
\begin{align}
P(X \le x) &= P(\frac{Z_1}{Z_1+Z_2} \le x)\\
&= P(Z_1 \le xZ_1+xZ_2)\\
&= P(Z_1 \le Z_2(\frac{x}{1-x}))\\
&= P(Z_1 \le g(Z_2))\\
\end{align}
$$

At this point I would like to use CDF for $Z_1$ like this $1-e^{-x*g(Z_2)}$ but the key uses
$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}P(Z_1 \le\frac{x}{1-x}z)dz$.  How do I make this jump because it doesn't seem to follow from the work I have done.

Comment: Your equations are correct but you are doing something incorrect with them.  You have $Pr[Z_1 \leq Z_2(x/(1-x))]$.  This is the probability of an event involving two random variables (so it is a real number).  It is not correct to say that is $F_{Z_1}(Z_2 x/(1-x))$, since this value is a function $F()$ applied to a random variable $Z_2$, so it is again a random variable.  Thus, you want to compute a (non-random) probability, but you are incorrectly turning it into a random quantity. Randomness is escaping out the back door.

Comment: You need to first condition on the value of $Z_2=z$ in order to compute the probability of hte event $Pr[Z_1 \leq z(x/(1-x)) | Z_2 = z]$.

Answer (score 0):

We are given a real number $x$. Note that:

1) $Pr[Z_1 \leq Z_2 x/(1-x)]$ is a probability, a real number (non-random).

2) $F_{Z_1}(Z_2 x/(1-x))$ is a function of a random variable, and hence is itself a random variable.

So the two have completely different types.  It makes no sense to say $Pr[Z_1 \leq Z_2 x/(1-x)] = F_{Z_1}(Z_2 x/(1-x))$.  It would be like saying $log(x) = blue$.

---

As in my comment above:  To compute $Pr[Z_1 \leq Z_2 x/(1-x)]$, you should first condition on the value of $Z_2$ being a given real number $z$, so you compute $Pr[Z_1 \leq z x/(1-x)|Z_2=z]$.

---

Here is a related fallacy:  Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector with non-negative components.  For each $z>0$ define the following function:

$$ h(z) = E[Y^z] $$

Now we understand that $E[Y^X]$ is a real number (nothing random about it).  But one might (incorrectly) write: 
$$E[Y^X] = h(X)$$
The above equation makes no sense, since the left-hand-side is a real number (nothing random), while the right-hand-side is random.

A correct computation of $E[Y^X]$ is as follows:  For simplicity, assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  Then: 
$$ E[Y^X] = \int_{x=0}^{\infty} E[Y^x|X=x]f_X(x)dx = \int_{x=0}^{\infty} E[Y^x]f_X(x)dx = \int_{x=0}^{\infty} h(x)f_X(x)dx $$